# ROR Activeadmin Device. How to get their styles files of the login page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to edit the view authorization in the activeadmin. I got views with the command `rails g devise:views admin_users`. How to get them [style files](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/tree/master/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `rails generate active_admin:assets`. That should generate the JS and CSS files under `app/assets/`. Source: https://activeadmin.info/0-installation.html#setting-up-active-admin